# Ask this computation of joint probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

This question is from my textbook: mathematical statistics: basic ideas and selected topics: volume 1, page 50.

Suppose $X=(Z,Y)^T$ where $Y=Z+\theta W, \theta >0$, $Z$ and $W$ are independent $N(0,1)$. Then

$$f(x, \theta)=f(z,y,\theta)=f(z)f_\theta (y|z)=\varphi(z) \theta^{-1} \varphi((y-z)\theta^{-1})$$

Here $\varphi()$ denotes the standard normal distribution.

(a) I am confused about the second equal. My understanding is $f(z,y,\theta)=f(z)f (y, \theta|z)$.

(b) I don't understand the third equal sign.

Comment: For (a) there is no essential difference between $f_\theta(y \mid z)$ and $f(y,\theta \mid z)$ especially since $\theta$ is a constant parameter of the calculation not depending on $z$

Comment: For (b) you have $f(z)= \varphi(z)$ while for the other part might want to consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family

Comment: @Henry For (b), I am considering that given Z, our Y now only depends on W. Now Y and W are location-scale family, right?

Comment: Indeed that seems reasonable if $Z=z$ is given; if so then $Y \sim N(z,\theta^2)$ and $\frac{Y-z}{\theta}=W\sim N(0,1)$

Comment: By using your location-scale family website, I verify my logic.